# How to define a type of object property

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

When I get an object with different property types I need to define a type of each object property and depending on it - serialize each property with different method. I know how to serialize object with different type, but how can I said that this property should be used with this method and another with another method I don't know.

Here is an example of my class:

```
[XmlType("Person")] // define Type

public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("PropertyType")]
    public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public Dictionary<object, object> Age { get; set; }
}
```

here I serialize int,string, List properties

```
public static string XmlSerializeUsualTypes(Object item) {}
```

here I serialize Dictionary properties

```
public static string XmlSerializeDictionaryTypes(Object item) {}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I need to serialize object of class Person, it has property with property type Dictionary that is non serializable with xml serialization, so I have wrote methodes that serialize usual properties and dictionary typed property. Now I need to serialize different property with different methode? but don't know how to tell that this property should be used with this method and another with another method I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit `Dictionary<K,V>` and implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface using your `XmlSerializeDictionaryTypes` method.

```
public class MyXmlDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K,V>, IXmlSerializable
{
    // … implement IXmlSerializable methods here …
}
```

When the `XmlSerializer` encounters a property implementing `IXmlSerializable` *(e.g. when serializing the `Person` object)* it will call [`IXmlSerializable.WriteXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml.aspx) *(implemented on the poperty's type, e.g. `MyXmlDictionary<K,V>` in our case)* to serialize that property.

Comment: I use this interface and had Inherit Dictionary<K,V>. I ask how to finish my code to realize this

Comment: but how can I tell to serialize property of object in current methode, that serialize exactly dictionary?